# Modern equivalent to rsymtab for reconstructing symbol table for statically linked / stripped binaries?

Tags: linux, elf, symbols

I'm working with a 32-bit ELF binary that (I believe) has been statically linked against a few different third-party libraries. It has also been stripped, so I don't have much to go on with respect to its symbol table.

I came across the old [rsymtab](http://reverse.lostrealm.com/tools/rsymtab.html) tool that claims to be able to match object code from non-stripped libraries to code in your executable. It would then generate a symbol table file when it finds matches. Unfortunately, rsymtab is more than ten years old and build against a library that doesn't exist on modern Linux systems (libbfd). Is there any modern equivalent to this tool?

(Is this even the right approach when reversing a static/stripped binary? Should the object code be expected to match exactly between the binary and the right version of the third-party lib?)